# How to create 802.11 Frames?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, wifi

How can someone programmatically create 802.11 Frames?

On this side it is explained how a 802.11 MAC Frames look like.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757419(v=ws.10).aspx

Is it possible to create 802.11 MAC Frames using the Berkeley Socket API? Or is there another library to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You will need something called frame injection (with radiotap header). It can be easily done with libpcap and pcap_inject function.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called [raw sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket). And yes, most Berkely sockets APIs support raw sockets access. Note that you might need elevated privileges on your operating system of choice in order to be allowed to craft and send raw packets. There is a risk of exploitation which is why it's often restricted.

[This manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw) describes the support for raw sockets in Linux.